# Can I dump memory to get decrypted data that encrypted with TDE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, tde

I want to know how much data is secured in SQL Server that enabled TDE. I read some articles about TDE in SQL Server like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Note that this part:

*Encryption of the database file is performed at the page level. The pages in an encrypted database are encrypted before they are written to disk and **decrypted when read into memory***.

Does this mean if I dump the SQL Server memory, I can access decrypted data? If somebody just runs select statement on some table, can I dump the whole table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TDE encrypts data at rest, not in motion.  Both a memory dump or select statement will return clear data.